# TabNavigator (on Tab click) doesn't calling lifecycle method of React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I Will add the tabBar in my Apps the lifecycle of react native called at first time it fine. Also get data from webservice at first time. But now I will change the tab on click no one lifecycle delegate called. I want to update view every time when change on tab.

**Its means want to updated view with webservice on change with tab.**

No one method is called :

```
componentWillMount
componentDidMount
componentWillReceiveProps
shouldComponentUpdate
componentWillUpdate
componentWillUnmount
componentDidUpdate
```

**GIF** :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
**its depend on how you used tabbar** 

const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  {
    Tab1: { screen: TabList1 },
    Tab2: { screen: TabList2 },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Tab1',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
  },
);

<Tabs
          screenProps={{
            onRefresh: this.yourrefeshcall,
          }}
      />


then 

Tabs = (props) => {
    if (props) {
      return (
        < Tabs
            navigation={props.navigation}
            screenProps={{
              onRefresh: this.yourrefeshcall,

            }}
        />
      );
    }

**make your call here** 

yourrefeshcall=()=>{

}
```

Comment: where we define the Tabs = (props) => {

Comment: can you updated code for me, so that i will easily use it